# Problem with  inserting images on specific page

Tags: graphics, pdfpages

I am producing a pdf file using LaTeX. Now I want to insert some images on page 13 and page 14 of my LaTeX generated pdf document. That images are stored in some other pdf file. So I want to get that images and insert at the bottom of page 13 and page 14. I tried with `\includegrapics` and `\includepdfpages` but both are inserting images at the beginning of the document. I need to insert images at the bottom of page 13 and 14, can anyone help me how to insert images on that specific page. I tried like this.

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,leqno,twoside]{article}
 \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[english]{babel}
 \usepackage{multirow}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{pdfpages}

 \begin{document}

  \includegraphics[width=5in,height=5in,page=1]{apsi.pdf}
   \includegraphics[width=5in,height=5in,page=1]{apsi.pdf}

  [% FOREACH st IN Service %]
  Name,Id: [% st.Id %], [% st.Name %]

  des:[% st.Description %]

  Customers:[% FOREACH softservice IN st.Customers %]
            [% FOREACH swid IN softservice.SW %]
            [% swid.Service %] 
            [% FOREACH st IN Service %][% IF swid.Service == st.Id %]
            ([% st.Name %]) 

            [% END %] [% END %][% END %][% END %]
  \newpage
  [% END %]
 \end{document}
```

I don't know how to insert a pdf image at a specific page number in the LaTeX generated pdf document. Anybody suggest me how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\includegraphics` inserts the graphic where you write the command.  It could even be used in the middle of a paragraph.  So if you write the command at the beginning of the document as above, the graphic will appear at the beginning of the document.  Look at your text without the graphics and write `\includegraphics` where the graphic should appear, taking into account  its size.  If you want the graphics exactly at the bottom and top of certain pages, you may use the figure environment with placement option `b` and `t`: `\begin{figure}[b]...\end{figure}` somewhere on the appropriate pages.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it help me how to assign figure at top or bottom of page but still I am facing problem with page number I want insert my image. How to insert this figure on page 13 or some other page. Can give some suggestion or example.